# Simple way to save data for clock in clock out system

Tags: java, mysql, storage

I'm trying to creat a clock in clock out system, but I'm having trouble with saving the data. It doesen't needs to be secure.

First I tried to use a txt file. However that was bad and I tried to make a little database in MySQL ,that looks like this.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `clocking` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `staff_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `clock_in_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `clock_out_date` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `staffs` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

But I never used Java with MySQL and I felt like this was overkill.

So, Is there any better way to save the data for this project? I'm relatively new to Java and this website.

Thanks

Comment: Looks good (besides missing keys). Go for it.

Comment: The problem is that I never used JDBC and I'm not that good with Java. I would prefer an other way, especially if it's possible to save it offline.

Comment: If a file did not work for you, then you do not have so much options with limited programming skills.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign default value to **clock_in_date/Clock_out_date** column .. because sometime staff person might forget to put entry of going out of office (be it writing in file or showing your ID card in front of system).

**clock_in_date/clock_out_date** column names doesn't look good as you expect employee to come and leave office on a single day or at max with two days when you are working in shifts . I would recommand **clock_in_time/clock_out_time** to be used.

This [URL](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html) has a sample example how to connect MYSQL with Java .

you should have mysql-jdbc connector jar present in your classpath.

Comment: Yeah but it was more for experimenting. I could create a connection and read out of the tables.